# Thymleaf cannot parse template with fragment

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create template with some dynamic data using fragment I created to format with CSS. My app based on Spring Boot.
There is my fragment:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" th:fragment="common_error(code,message,description, supportMessage)" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title th:text="|${code} — ${message}|">Title here</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/error.css}" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" th:href="@{/images/favicon.ico}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1><span>error</span><span th:replace="${code}">500</span></h1>
    <p class="title" th:insert="${message}"></p>
    <span th:replace="${description}">Description here</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="triangle-container"><div></div></div>
    <p class="support" th:insert="${supportMessage}" >
        If you have further questions, please visit<br>
        <a href="#">support.example.com</a>
    </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I use this fragment with static data like this, then all works fine.

```html
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="fragments/error :: common_error(~{::[@id='code']/text()},~{::[@id='message']/text()},~{::.description}, _)">
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="code">500</div>
    <div id="message">Internal Server Error</div>
    <p class="description">Sorry, we are currently experiencing technical difficulties.</p>
    <p class="description">Our team is addressing the issues and will make the system available as soon as possible.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I try to add some variables, then I receive an error during template parsing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
       th:replace="fragments/error::common_error(~{::[@id='code']/text()},~{::[@id='message']/text()},~{::.description}, ~{::.support_message})">
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>error<span id="code" th:text="${code} ?: #{error.default.code}"></span></h1>
    <p id="message" th:text="${message} ?: #{error.default.message}"></p>
    <div class="description"><span th:utext="${description}"></span></div>
    <p class="support_message" th:utext="#{support.default.message}"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
    Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error resolving fragment: "${code}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "fragments/error" - line 13, col 33)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving fragment: "${code}": template or fragment could not be resolved (template: "fragments/error" - line 13, col 33)
```

Please help :)

UPD When I exclude fragment from my template, then it also works fine and my variables inserted ok.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my solution in this way:
In the template, I renamed the "description" variable to "custom_description" to avoid variable name conflicts between the template and the fragment.
I also added an additional "titleMessage" variable to the fragment for correct rendering.
And also I changed the way I pass my variables to template and fragment as per this [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40051174/14748320).

Fragment:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html lang="en" th:fragment="common_error(code, titleMessage, message, description, supportMessage)" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title th:text="|${code} — ${titleMessage}|">Title here</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400" rel="stylesheet">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/error.css}" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" th:href="@{/images/favicon.ico}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h1><span>error</span><span th:replace="${code}">500</span></h1>
    <p class="title" th:insert="${message}"></p>
    <span th:replace="${description}">Description here</span>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="triangle-container"><div></div></div>
    <div class="support">
        <p th:insert="${supportMessage}" >
            If you have further questions, please visit
        </p>
        <p><a href="#">support.example.com</a></p>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
       th:replace="fragments/error::common_error(~{::[@id='code']/text()}, #{error.default.message}, ~{::[@id='message']/text()}, ~{::.description}, ~{::[@id='support_message']/text()})">
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>error<span id="code">500</span></h1>
    <div id="message">[[#{error.default.message}]]</div>
    <div class="description"><span th:utext="${custom_description}"></span></div>
    <p id="support_message" >[[#{support.default.message}]]</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And now everything works OK.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).